# When does IIS log 500 error? Are they all fatal?

Tags: wcf, iis

I am hosting a WCF service in IIS for my clients to call. During the load testing, all the client calls returns well, but I see a lot of 500 errors in the IIS log file. Such as below:

```
2012-02-09 08:01:37 192.168.0.1 POST /XXX/Service.svc - 443 - 192.168.0.2 - 200 0 0 8983
2012-02-09 08:01:37 192.168.0.1 POST /XXX/Service.svc - 443 - 192.168.0.2 - 500 0 0 531
2012-02-09 08:01:37 192.168.0.1 POST /XXX/Service.svc - 443 - 192.168.0.2 - 500 0 0 546
2012-02-09 08:01:37 192.168.0.1 POST /XXX/Service.svc - 443 - 192.168.0.2 - 500 0 0 546
2012-02-09 08:01:37 192.168.0.1 POST /XXX/Service.svc - 443 - 192.168.0.2 - 200 0 0 14155
```

Questions are:

1. When does IIS log 500 error?
2. Since all the client requets seem to be satisfied, can we safely ignore these 500 errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The 500 error code is a generic HTTP error state that indicates a faulty state of the web server.

There can be innumerable reasons for receiving such error. Without further analysis there is no way to determine what's causing the error.

Try debugging your code step-by-step and check the exception being generated.